# Javascript scrollIntoView() middle alignment?

Tags: javascript, js-scrollintoview

Javascript `.scrollIntoView(boolean)` provide only two alignment option.

1. top
2. bottom

What if I want to scroll the view such that. I want to bring particular element somewhere in middle of the page?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Use `window.scrollTo()` for this. Get the top of the element you want to move to, and subtract one half the window height.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ThinkingStiff/MJ69d/

```js
Element.prototype.documentOffsetTop = function () {
    return this.offsetTop + ( this.offsetParent ? this.offsetParent.documentOffsetTop() : 0 );
};

var top = document.getElementById( 'middle' ).documentOffsetTop() - ( window.innerHeight / 2 );
window.scrollTo( 0, top );
```

Comment: It's a bit inefficient to walk up the whole parent chain

Comment: i like the `offsetTop - (container / 2)`. simple, but i didn't think of it.

Comment: this didn't work inside a WebView, so I settled for a fake URI with #target on the end and no centering

Answer (score 225):

try this :

```
 document.getElementById('myID').scrollIntoView({
            behavior: 'auto',
            block: 'center',
            inline: 'center'
        });
```

refer here for more information and options : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView

Comment: in combination with the polyfill, this is the best answer. https://www.npmjs.com/package/smoothscroll-polyfill

Comment: Only Chrome and Opera fully support block and inline, not even the smoothscroll polyfill does. It's the solution we want, but sadly not the one that works.

Comment: I am using the same solution in my project on IE11, Firefox, Chrome and Safari with Angular 5.

Comment: @Sri7 Safari, IE and Edge do not understand the object-option of `scrollIntoView` and do whatever they want. Even on latest versions; I just tested it again.

Comment: I can confirm this does not work on mobile safari as of today. window.scrollBy works.

Comment: there is also a `scrollIntoViewIfNeeded(true)` if your browser supports https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoViewIfNeeded

Comment: This is the best solution for Chrome

Comment: @ryanrain The smoothscroll-polyfill package seems abandoned and does not support `block` and `inline` parameters. Use this instead: https://www.npmjs.com/package/seamless-scroll-polyfill

Comment: Working in an Angular component... With inline: 'center' the right-hand side moved inward, messing everything up, but inline: 'end' fixed that and now it's centering with block: 'center'.

Comment: 2022. as of today. it works on Safari on desktop.

Answer (score 90):

It is possible to use [`getBoundingClientRect()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect) to get all the information you need to achieve this. For example, you could do something like this:

```
const element = document.getElementById('middle');
const elementRect = element.getBoundingClientRect();
const absoluteElementTop = elementRect.top + window.pageYOffset;
const middle = absoluteElementTop - (window.innerHeight / 2);
window.scrollTo(0, middle);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/cxe73c22/

This solution is more efficient than walking up parent chain, as in the accepted answer, and doesn't involve polluting the global scope by extending prototype ([generally considered bad practice in javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain#Bad_practice_Extension_of_native_prototypes)).

The `getBoundingClientRect()` method is supported in all modern browsers.

Comment: Sadly, this breaks with absolute positioned elements.

Comment: Can you edit your answer to include how to do it when the element is in a scrollable container instead of the page? I tried: https://jsfiddle.net/qwxvts4u/1/

Comment: Solved with the help of [@KevinB](https://stackoverflow.com/users/400654/kevin-b) https://jsfiddle.net/5ce062tn/

Comment: This solution worked for me *with fixed header*

Answer (score 22):

```
document.getElementById("id").scrollIntoView({block: "center"});
```

Comment: I needed this for a vertically scrolling table with fixed header and this is working for me.

Answer (score 15):

Scrolling to the middle of an element works well if its parent element has the css: `overflow: scroll;`

If it's a vertical list, you can use `document.getElementById("id").scrollIntoView({block: "center"});` and it will scroll your selected element to the vertical middle of the parent element.

Cheers to Gregory R. and Hakuna for their good answers.

*Further Reading:*

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow

Answer (score 10):

You can do it in two steps :

```
myElement.scrollIntoView(true);
var viewportH = Math.max(document.documentElement.clientHeight, window.innerHeight || 0);
window.scrollBy(0, -viewportH/2); // Adjust scrolling with a negative value here
```

You can add the height of the element if you want to center it globaly, and not center its top :

```
myElement.scrollIntoView(true);
var viewportH = Math.max(document.documentElement.clientHeight, window.innerHeight || 0);
window.scrollBy(0, (myElement.getBoundingClientRect().height-viewportH)/2);
```

Comment: this is the best answer for year 2018. first use normal "scrollIntoView", because "center" option is broken in Firefox 36 to 58 , and options are not supported by IE, see this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView#Browser_compatibility . then you can center the scroll by calculate half of the viewport and move the scroll there.

Comment: Thanks, I can confirm that this worked on KaiOS where the "center" value of scrollIntoView isn't supported.

Answer (score 3):

With JQuery I use this:

```
function scrollToMiddle(id) {

    var elem_position = $(id).offset().top;
    var window_height = $(window).height();
    var y = elem_position - window_height/2;

    window.scrollTo(0,y);

}
```

Example:

```
<div id="elemento1">Contenido</div>

<script>
    scrollToMiddle("#elemento1");
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Improving the answer of `@Rohan Orton` to work for vertical and horizontal scroll.

> The [Element.getBoundingClientRect()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect) method returns the size of an element and its position relative to the viewport.

```js
var ele = $x("//a[.='Ask Question']");
console.log( ele );

scrollIntoView( ele[0] );

function scrollIntoView( element ) {
    var innerHeight_Half = (window.innerHeight >> 1); // Int value
                        // = (window.innerHeight / 2); // Float value
    console.log('innerHeight_Half : '+ innerHeight_Half);

    var elementRect = element.getBoundingClientRect();

    window.scrollBy( (elementRect.left >> 1), elementRect.top - innerHeight_Half);
}
```

Using [`Bitwise operator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators) right shift to get int value after dividing.

```js
console.log( 25 / 2 ); // 12.5
console.log( 25 >> 1 ); // 12
```

Answer (score 2):

None of the solutions on this page work when a container other than the window/document is scrolled. The `getBoundingClientRect` approach fails with absolute positioned elements.

In that case we need to determine the scrollable parent first and scroll it instead of the window. Here is a solution that works in all current browser versions and should even work with IE8 and friends. The trick is to scroll the element to the top of the container, so that we know exactly where it is, and then subtract half of the screen's height.

```
function getScrollParent(element, includeHidden, documentObj) {
    let style = getComputedStyle(element);
    const excludeStaticParent = style.position === 'absolute';
    const overflowRegex = includeHidden ? /(auto|scroll|hidden)/ : /(auto|scroll)/;

    if (style.position === 'fixed') {
        return documentObj.body;
    }
    let parent = element.parentElement;
    while (parent) {
        style = getComputedStyle(parent);
        if (excludeStaticParent && style.position === 'static') {
            continue;
        }
        if (overflowRegex.test(style.overflow + style.overflowY + style.overflowX)) {
            return parent;
        }
        parent = parent.parentElement;
    }

    return documentObj.body;
}

function scrollIntoViewCentered(element, windowObj = window, documentObj = document) {
    const parentElement = getScrollParent(element, false, documentObj);
    const viewportHeight = windowObj.innerHeight || 0;

    element.scrollIntoView(true);
    parentElement.scrollTop = parentElement.scrollTop - viewportHeight / 2;

    // some browsers (like FireFox) sometimes bounce back after scrolling
    // re-apply before the user notices.
    window.setTimeout(() => {
        element.scrollIntoView(true);
        parentElement.scrollTop = parentElement.scrollTop - viewportHeight / 2;
    }, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To support all options in `scrollIntoViewOptions` for all browsers it's better to use **seamless-scroll-polyfill** (https://www.npmjs.com/package/seamless-scroll-polyfill)

Worked for me.

Here is a link with explanation https://github.com/Financial-Times/polyfill-library/issues/657