# Scroll Into View with certain parameters

Tags: javascript, c#, selenium

I have a scroll into view already which works, however I was thinking to make it smarter.

This is my code so far

`((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", element);`

which is hooked into my OnClicking event listener - so whenever it goes to click an element, first it scrolls it into view.

This is great and it does what I want it to, however when running my tests my page is scrolling up and down even if the element is in the middle of the screen.

So my question is, *how do I set a parameter on this to say, if the element is below 3/4 on the viewable screen **then** scroll*?

Comment: Means do you want to scroll when element is not displayed on the screen?? Right

Comment: @SaurabhGaur I want to scroll only when element is below 75% of the screen.

Answer (score 1):

I think. You can try it.

```
var element = driver.FindElement(By.Xpath("//*/blabla"));
var js = driver as IJavaScriptExecutor;
js.ExecuteScript("window.scrollTo(" + element.Location.X + ","+(element.Location.Y - 100) + ");");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript to get the X/Y cordinates:

```
var cumulativeOffset = function(element) {
    var top = 0, left = 0;
    do {
        top += element.offsetTop  || 0;
        left += element.offsetLeft || 0;
        element = element.offsetParent;
    } while(element);

    return {
        top: top,
        left: left
    };
};
```

In this case you want the Y coordinate. 
And use this: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_scrollto.asp

Or... take a look at this:
[Javascript scrollIntoView() middle alignment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8922107/javascript-scrollintoview-middle-alignment)

Comment: How do I use this with selenium?

Comment: Are you coding in Java? Php/Behat? Python? You can execute this as javascript. For java: https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/JavascriptExecutor.html

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old post, but if people looking for answer, here it is

```
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView({block: \"center\"});", webElement);
```