# How to scroll to the bottom of the selected div?

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can I scroll to the bottom of the desired div? Right now, it will add the height value to the scrollTop which will made the scroll to scroll to only that specific height. I want it to scroll down to the last of the 5th
div.
There are 9 h1, so I want it to scroll upto the bottom of the 5th h1

```js
const scrollbtn = document.getElementById('scrl');
var objDiv = document.querySelectorAll('.each');
const mycontainer = document.querySelector('.container');

scrollbtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
const itemHeight = objDiv[5].scrollHeight;
    mycontainer.scrollTop += itemHeight;
})
```

```css
body {
  background: tomato;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

.container {
  max-height: 200px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  background: white;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

.each {
  padding-top: 10px;
  background: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1 class="each">Test</h1>
  <h1 class="each">Test</h1>
  <h1 class="each">Test</h1>
  <h1 class="each">Test</h1>
  <h1 class="each">Test</h1>
  <h1 class="each">Test</h1>
  <h1 class="each">Test</h1>
  <h1 class="each">Test</h1>
  <h1 class="each">Test</h1>
</div>

<button id="scrl">
  scroll
</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [scrollIntoView](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView)

```
scrollbtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  objDiv[objDiv.length-1].scrollIntoView(); // change objDiv.length-1 to 4 if you want to scroll to the 5th H
})
```

You can add options like `{behavior: "smooth", block: "end", inline: "nearest"}`

```js
const scrollbtn = document.getElementById('scrl');
var objDiv = document.querySelectorAll('.each');
const mycontainer = document.querySelector('.container');

scrollbtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  objDiv[objDiv.length - 1].scrollIntoView({
    behavior: "smooth",
    block: "end",
    inline: "nearest"
  })
})
```

```css
body {
  background: tomato;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

.container {
  max-height: 200px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  background: white;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

.each {
  padding-top: 10px;
  background: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<button id="scrl">
  scroll
</button>

<div style="height:500px">Dummy to see the behaviour of the page</div>
<div class="container">
  <h1 class="each">Test</h1>
  <h1 class="each">Test</h1>
  <h1 class="each">Test</h1>
  <h1 class="each">Test</h1>
  <h1 class="each">Test</h1>
  <h1 class="each">Test</h1>
  <h1 class="each">Test</h1>
  <h1 class="each">Test</h1>
  <h1 class="each">Test</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: its scrolling to the end of page and the div

Comment: And what is expected behaviour? To not scroll the page?

Comment: I have updated the question, please check it :)

Comment: You can change objDiv.length-1 to 4 or 5 if you want

Comment: it scroll to the fifth one but not perfectly, it stops at middle of the 5th

Comment: Change some option as you wish https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8922107/javascript-scrollintoview-middle-alignment

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/xmurodz0/1/, when we keep clicking on the button it will progress to the next div, but at some point when it reaches the last div and when we click on the button it console log :- `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'scrollIntoView')`

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/sbt8qmg9/   `if (myvalue >= objDiv.length) return;`

Answer (score 1):

Jump to the 5th div immediately

```js
const scrollbtn = document.getElementById('scrl');
var objDiv = document.querySelectorAll('.each');
const mycontainer = document.querySelector('.container');

scrollbtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  mycontainer.scrollTop = objDiv[0].scrollHeight * 5 //the first height multiple by 5
})
```

```css
body {
  background: tomato;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

.container {
  max-height: 200px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  background: white;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

.each {
  padding-top: 10px;
  background: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1 class="each">Test</h1>
  <h1 class="each">Test</h1>
  <h1 class="each">Test</h1>
  <h1 class="each">Test</h1>
  <h1 class="each">Test</h1>
  <h1 class="each">Test</h1>
  <h1 class="each">Test</h1>
  <h1 class="each">Test</h1>
  <h1 class="each">Test</h1>
</div>

<button id="scrl">
      scroll
    </button>
```

Go through one by one till reaching out the the 5th

```js
const scrollbtn = document.getElementById('scrl');
var objDiv = document.querySelectorAll('.each');
const mycontainer = document.querySelector('.container');
let interval
scrollbtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  if (interval) {
    clearInterval(interval)
  }
  let index = 1
  interval = setInterval(() => {
    const itemHeight = objDiv[0].scrollHeight;
    mycontainer.scrollTop += itemHeight;
    index++
    if (index === 6) { //if it's already gone to the 5th, break the interval
      clearInterval(interval)
    }
  }, 300)
})
```

```css
body {
  background: tomato;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

.container {
  max-height: 200px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  background: white;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

.each {
  padding-top: 10px;
  background: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1 class="each">Test</h1>
  <h1 class="each">Test</h1>
  <h1 class="each">Test</h1>
  <h1 class="each">Test</h1>
  <h1 class="each">Test</h1>
  <h1 class="each">Test</h1>
  <h1 class="each">Test</h1>
  <h1 class="each">Test</h1>
  <h1 class="each">Test</h1>
</div>

<button id="scrl">
          scroll
        </button>
```

Comment: its scrolling to the end of the div, I want it to scroll to the end of the 5th `<h1 class="each">Test</h1>`

Comment: you want to scroll to the 5th immediately or go through one by one? @JoelSmith

Comment: I want to learn both ways, generally I want it to smoothly go to the 5th one :)

Comment: Hi! To add smoothness you can use element.scrollTo(options) with behavior: "smooth"

Docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollTo

Comment: @true_k we can also use `scroll-behavior: smooth;` in css

Comment: I updated my answer for both cases @JoelSmith

Comment: there is a problem, as we are doing it based on the height of the obj[0] and then multiply it by 5, what happen if we have the obj[0] height more than the height of the 5th one, then it will multiply the bigger height by 5 and it will not gonna stop at 5. but more than 5

Comment: then you can use `scrollIntoView` like `objDiv[4].scrollIntoView();` @JoelSmith

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/xmurodz0/1/, when we keep clicking on the button it will progress to the next div, but at some point when it reaches the last div and when we click on the button it console log :- `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'scrollIntoView')`

Comment: Add this to check your element is existing or not `if(!objDiv[myvalue]) {return}` before calling `scrollIntoView` @JoelSmith

Comment: @NickVu, once it reaches the last nothing happens and the overall scrolls stops, we can't scroll with the button anymore, does getting checking whether the scroll reaches the last and then stopping it? something like this? what would you do?

Comment: yes it is, if you reach the bottom, it won't scroll any further. If you want to scroll backwards, you can set `myvalue - 1`